# implement next button on ActionBar Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

How can I implement a "next" button on the actionbar in my App?

I have already implemented a back button in the bar.

```
val actionbar = supportActionBar
actionbar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

[image]

Comment: What you mean in Next Button

Comment: @JimaleAbdi a butto to pass to a  third activity

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is no next button but this is makes something like next button, as i understand your question you need to intent new activity in action bar

Step 1 create XML resource in res/menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/nxtbutton"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="nxtbtn" />
```

Then you need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` function in your `Activity` like this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menuTest, menu)
return true

}
```

Handling click events

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
R.id.nxtbutton -> {
     val intent = Intent(context, nextActivity::class.java);
      startActivity(intent);

      true
     }
     else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
```

Comment: If its works for you please up vote my answer also accept it, to help the others